# Python mutate and return in method

Tags: python, oop

I'm learning Python and I have read that a function should either mutate something or return something, but not both. I'm not sure whether this also applies to methods.

I want to use a method to mutate an attribute of a class and also return the amount by which the attribute was changed. Is this un-Pythonic?

Here's a simplied example of my code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.resistance = 10

    def add_to_x(self, value):
        amount_to_add = value - self.resistance
        self.x += amount_to_add
        return amount_to_add
```

Comment: That seems a reasonable behavior. To be "more pythonic" you should add a docstring to explain what the function does: "Increment x by value minus resistance and return the increment."

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.